# arguments in GraphQl operations?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I can't understand the relationship between arguments passed with the client query and the arguments in the operations in the server side in schema and resolvers

In [Apollo docks](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/), they are creating space trips booking app that dispaly launches info to the client, the app display 20 results by default and when clicking the view more button it shows another 20 and so on!!

now, the query in the client side looks like this:

**launches.tsx**

```
  query GetLaunchList($after: String) {
    launches(after: $after) {
      cursor  
      hasMore
      launches {
        ...LaunchTile  // a fragment
      }
    }
  }
```

In schema, the `Query` field `launches` looks like this

```
type Query {
  launches( 
    pageSize: Int
    after: String
  ): LaunchConnection!

 type LaunchConnection {
    cursor: String!
    hasMore: Boolean!
    launches: [Launch]!
  }
```

**resolvers.js**:

```
Query: {
    launches: async (_, { pageSize = 20, after }, { dataSources }) => {
      const allLaunches = // fetching data from a data source

      const launches = paginateResults({
        after,
        pageSize,
        results: allLaunches,
      });

      return {
        launches,
        cursor: launches.length ? launches[launches.length - 1].cursor : null,
        hasMore: // some logic to check if there are more results
      };
    }
 }
```

Now, i can't understand how **after** argument in the client side query relate to the schema and resolver, i understand that the client need to send this variable to the server to be used by the schema and the resolver because the server need to know what data should be sent to the client because the results are paginated!!

How graphql relates **after** argument  to **after**  argument in launches in schema and resolver??

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/execution/

Comment: @xadm
I understand how queries get executed but i can't understand how pageSize argument preceded after argument here, how the graphql server know which one is sent by the client??

Comment: passed args are in 2nd resolver arg ... `console.log(args)`, decompose (`const { pageSize = 20, after } = args;`) later

Comment: @xadm
this is what i am talking about, what if i changed the name of `after` argument to something like `cursor` for example, how the server would recognize it, something is not clear in that part!!

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/

Comment: @xadm
`after` is the only argument sent by the client

in the schema, there is two arguments>>..how graphql server know which one is sent by the client??

it is not about destructuring at all

Comment: **it is destructuring with default value** - when not provided ... you can pass two args, they will be used, both passed ... you can use this query without variables passed, null for after will be used

Comment: @xadm
it turns to be a destructuring problem in the end, if you want to post an answer i would be here to accept!!

Comment: there was no graphql problem at all, just js ES6 syntax ;)

Comment: @xadm but u helped me understand where my problem is, any way thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one thing can be 'mysterious', not obvious - inline destructuring ...

From [general graphql server docs](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/) - resolver function takes 4 args `(obj, args, context, info)`, where

> **args** - The arguments provided to the field in the GraphQL query.

Your resolver

> ```
> `launches: async (_, { pageSize = 20, after }, { dataSources }) => {`
> ```

makes use of ES6 destructuring assignment syntax, a 'shortened version' of:

```
launches: async (_, args, context) => {
  const { pageSize = 20, after } = args;
  const { dataSources } = context;`
```

From schema `launches` can have 2 args (`pageSize` and `after`), they are passed to resolver as `args` object props.

Both args are optional (nullable - from schema, too), but handled a bit differently - see destructuring declaration with default/fallback:

```
  const { pageSize = 20, after } = args;
```

For both args missing (not provided by client) `pageSize` will use default value `20` while `after` will be `null`-ed.

For both args passed - both values will be used (instead of defaults).

This is a standard JS ES6 behaviour described [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/).